# How to see Azure cosmosdb Attachment in azure cosmosdb portal area?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I had already inserted my attachments in azure cosmos documentDB.
After I inserting the attachment I can't see any attached attachments in my cosmosDB portal.

[image: Click here]

My question is where I'm going to see my uploaded attachment in azure cosmosdb portal area. I don't know where my attachments are showing the azure portal and I'm using the azure cosmosdb trial account. Please anyone answer me.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can view it in the **portal**,

From the **[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources)**

> Azure Cosmos DB allows you to store binary blobs/media either with
>   Azure Cosmos DB (maximum of 2 GB per account) or to your own remote
>   media store. It also allows you to represent the metadata of a media
>   in terms of a special document called attachment. An attachment in
>   Azure Cosmos DB is a special (JSON) document that references the
>   media/blob stored elsewhere. An attachment is simply a special
>   document that captures the metadata (for example, location, author
>   etc.) of a media stored in a remote media storage.

**BTW**

Though cosmosdb allows you to store files (they are stored as attachments), I would not recommend using it.

If you noticed a sample JSON above Under attachments there is a line "`media": "/media/5VEpAMZpeasdfdfdAAAAAOFDl80B".` This is actually the link to the stored binary payload. And you need to query that URI to get the payload.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but I want to see my inserted attachments. Is it possible or not?

Comment: In portal you cannot, but there are plugins avaiable to download and view

Comment: It looks like referenced link content has changed and there's nothing about attachments anymore. I'm having trouble finding information about attachment storage, as in https://www.slideshare.net/MohitChhabra1/azure-document-dbcosmos-db they say "attachment stored in Azure Blobs", but I can't find any official documentation about that.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: `If you noticed a sample JSON above Under attachments there is a line "media": ` where do you see this sample JSON with `media` attribute in azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

I did a [blog post](https://docdb.info/azure-cosmos-db-document-attachment-storage-comparison/) on Cosmos DB Attachment Storage Comparison

If you download and install [Azure DocumentDB Studio](https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio) , you can view most attachment media types

Comment: Looks like link does not work, in google it is even related to spam keywords.